# Stream multiple langauges audio from a playing video on a local live-streaming server

Tags: android, node.js, synchronization, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I have a case where I need to have a video being played *repeatedly* (looped) on a server (that video is being showed on a connected screen) and a client on the same wireless network that can get the current playing video **audio stream/s in-sync with video** that is being played on the server (the video may have multiple languages or could be *linked with multiple audio files* that needs to be streamed in-sync to that playing video).

Is there a ***Nodejs package or a library*** that I can use to achieve this scenario? and a streaming protocol/server that is easy to use or program those features in the client without too much hassle with the sync and stream?

I'm looking for support on the client side for mobile devices (preferably browser dependent) that can get the stream with Javascript (which is the simpler for me) or something else and potentially run as an full-screen app on the mobile device.

My plan is to have an app on mobile devices where a user can chose a language and video playing on screens to listen to in-sync with the video, like choosing a channel where they can connect to and listen to the audio of that video over the wireless network, So I'm looking for a way or a solutions to program this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you pull the video and all audio streams to the client, then select language and switch audio stream by the player?

Comment: @Winlin
What I ended up doing, is using Python OpenCV to play the video on the server and have an API which returns the current playing frame from OpenCV [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568804/get-current-video-playing-position-using-cv2-in-python), the audio files (with multiple languages) for the video should be already on the client, the client then requests the API to see what frame (which could be converted to time in ms) is currently being played and play the audio from that specific time.